# delphi trlReport com Group não carrega o primeiro registro

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, relatório

Tenho o retorno do sql:

```
|dt_producao| 
|20/09/2016 |
|20/09/2016 |
|20/09/2016 |
|21/09/2016 |
|21/09/2016 |
|22/09/2016 |
|24/09/2016 |
```

Estou tentando criar um relatório que me faça a junção:

```
|dt_producao|
|20/09/2016 |
|21/09/2016 |
|22/09/2016 |
|24/09/2016 |
```

No delphi coloquei os componentes um dentro do outro conforme a sequencia da descrição a baixo.

```
TRLReport vinculado ao meu data source
TrlGroup quebrando pela data
TRLBand com bandType btFooter
TRLDBText relacionando o meu dt_producao
```

Na hora de imprimir ele esta ignorando o primeiro registro e imprimindo do segundo em diante.

Comment: Não sei exatamente como está seu código, mas é importante que o dataset esteja no primeiro registro `Dataset.First;`. Podes confirmar?

Comment: ele esta no primeiro registro.

Comment: Uma pergunta: Porque o `bandtype` está como `btFooter`? Já tentou, ao menos para teste, colocá-lo como **Detail**?

Comment: se eu colocar Detail na Band ele vai me trazer todos os registros.